# Ubuntu LTS Notebook can only use Network Printer while a Mac Os Computer is also online in the network

Tags: server, printing, mac, raspberrypi

I have set up a Raspberry Pi as a Printer server in my Network. At first everything worked perfectly without any problems.

My main PC with Manjaro still has no problems. The Problem is the Ubuntu LTS 18.04 Notebook (Dell XPS 13) in the same network.

At first it worked without trouble, then days later I tried printing with it and it did not work. I checked the system settings and the printer was showing as printer not ready.

When then an iMac with macOS X also goes online in the same network (it was set to share its printers too, from before the dedicated printer server)

The Ubuntu Notebook saw the same printer twice: once from the Raspberry Pi and Once from the MAC.

The curious thing: The Printer that the Mac Shares shows now it's not ready on Ubuntu and the Printer shared by the Raspberry pi that previously showed not ready, now shows ready and is working fine.

As soon as I shutdown the iMAC or disable Printer sharing on its CUPS settings page the Ubuntu Notebook shows the shared printer from the Raspberry Pi as not ready.